# Does training a quantum circuit require the derivative of each quantum parameter?

Tags: qiskit

[image]

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEfyCvwcSkQ&list=PLOFEBzvs-VvqJwybFxkTiDzhf5E11p8BI&index=19

This doubt comes from Lab-4, the 2021 Qiskit Quantum Machine Learning Summer School. The specific difficulty in understanding is the two lines of code in the screenshot, where the meaning of index refers to theta2, and the specific formula seems to be the derivative of all thetas, so how to consider all the angle information comprehensively?

Comment: I think you need to improve your post. In many other StackExchange branches questions with screenshots only or links to some videos are frowned upon. This signals that the author of the question did not put enough effort to make the question clear, readable and respectful. If you are lazy to retype a simple math equation why someone should waste their time in providing a detailed well-written reply. The code should not be a screenshot, but a working copy that others can try running. Math equations should not be a screenshot but a latex-formatted equation.